# Is protein intake before workout useful?

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition, muscle-gain, protein, timing

So to give a little concept:

**My schedule:**

> 8:30 AM I start working
>
> 9:00 AM I eat breakfast like a salad with chicken (approx 15-20g
> protein).
>
> 13:00 PM Rice with chicken and veggies (30-45g)
>
> 15:00 PM Protein shake (25-30g)
>
> 17:00 PM WORKOUT (1 hour, intra workout amino acids, creatine)
>
> 18:30 PM Supper (usually variable but I try to stick to 30g protein)
>
> 20:00 PM Some kind of healthy dessert (20/30g protein)

**My workout:**

> 5 times a week
>
> Full body (focusing on a main group each time starting it with a
> compound)
>
> 1 hour
>
> Advanced lifter
>
> Always higher volume or higher weight per rep based on logs (if possible)
>
> Reps to failure

I weigh about 75kg so I reach my maximum amount of protein for the day.

So I don't really like my protein timing here because I get a lot of my proteins before my workout. If I were to do my workout at 7:00 AM for example before eating anything at all, would it make a huge change or is it irrelevant in terms of muscle gain? Of course, if I were to do that I would start with a shake rather than a salad in the morning.

If it really is that bad what would be a better recommendation if I were to keep my workout still at that time?

Comment: How many days a week do you work out, what kind of workouts are they, how intense do you go?

Comment: 5x a week full body and I try to push myself to my limits every workout. I always try to do either higher volume or higher weight per rep than the previous exercise based on my logs. I have a main focus for muscle groups each day for which I start with a compound exercise. I would call myself an advanced lifter.